# How to place a result into a matrix using R

Tags: r

So I have a code that I made here:

```
for (i in 2:25) { 
  print(i)
  print(cor.test(demo_data[, i], demo_data[, 1]))
}
```

So this basically runs every x variable (2:25) against my single y variable (1) and the output is the p value and correlation value.  What I want to do is put these outputs into a table that has columns for labels (what I tested), correlation (value from cor.test), and p value (another value from cor.test).  How should I go about doing that?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run all tests in one go with `apply`.
I will make up a dataset, since you have not posted one.

```
set.seed(9263)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 1000
demo_data <- matrix(runif(n, 0, 10), ncol = 25)

cor_list <- apply(demo_data[, -1], 2, cor.test, demo_data[, 1])
```

That's it.
Now in order to extract the values you want, remember that objects of class `"htest"`, the class returned by many `*.test` functions of base R, are nothing but lists with the class attribute changed. So, the standard extraction functions work.

```
corval <- sapply(cor_list, '[[', "estimate")
pval <- sapply(cor_list, '[[', "p.value")
labs <- paste("cor", 2:25, 1, sep = ".")

res <- data.frame(labels = labs, cor = corval, p.value = pval)

head(res)
#   labels          cor   p.value
#1 cor.2.1  0.190852493 0.2381344
#2 cor.3.1 -0.033208075 0.8388049
#3 cor.4.1  0.236789973 0.1412597
#4 cor.5.1  0.003775437 0.9815539
#5 cor.6.1 -0.079078805 0.6276482
#6 cor.7.1  0.003072550 0.9849876
```

Comment: You're awesome.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like:

```
result_matrix = matrix(nrow=24, ncol=3) 

for (i in 2:25) { 
  print(i)
  cor.result <- cor.test(demo_data[, i], demo_data[, 1])
  result_matrix[i-1,] <- c(demo_data[, i], cor.result$estimate, cor.result$p.value)
}
```

Hope it helps.